# My laptop can't detect WLAN connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My modem is an TP-LINK Model No-W8961N.
My Laptop is not able to see my wifi access point .
When I change the security to WEP it can detect it.
I reset my netwrok card from windows (I'm using Windows 10) but this is can't resolve my issue.

Have you please an idea ?
This is my WLAN configuration :

[image]

New information:
I have a dell inspiron Model 3543

[image]

Comment: What are the computer and its network adapter models?

Comment: Dell inspiron 3543 and a network card  Dell 1704

Answer (score 1):

The
[Dell Inspiron 3543 download page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3543-laptop/drivers)
has several updates for your computer (click "Find drivers").

The most important might be the
[Dell Wireless 1704 and 1708 Wi-Fi Driver](https://dl.dell.com/FOLDER03503644M/7/Network_Driver_XT97T_WN32_7.35.333.0_A04.EXE).

Try this driver. If it doesn't help, try the others that are marked as
"Critical" (careful with the BIOS update).

If nothing helps, the Dell Wireless 1704 adapter might have a problem.
You could try, as a last effort, to use an external USB wireless adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by fixing my router channel to a specific value (Put 12) instead of letting it on Auto Mode.
As I think , my laptop can't detect some specific channel configuration .
So when it's random it won't works correctly .